Can we define a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \left\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : \frac{5}{n} \right\}$ which is a bijection?
Can anyone help me checking my answer on this question?
Yes, our function is injective as we have different values for different arguments and it is surjective as all values are used.
Example:
Domain: $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \}$
Image: ${5, 1}$ ($5$ because $\frac{5}{1} = 5$ and $1$ because $\frac{5}{5} = 1$)

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

I don't see where you have argued anything.  Essentially, you just say it's injective because it is injective, and surjective because it is surjective.  Easiest way forward might be to describe the inverse.

I tried to format your question, but I am confused what is meant by it. Is the codomain the set of natural numbers that divide $5$? Or, e.g., the set of real numbers $x$ such that $x = \frac{5}{n}$ for some natural number $n$? Can you clarify?

$\frac52 \notin \mathbb{N}$ so $f$ is not well-defined.

If the codomain is meant to be ${\frac{5}{n}:n \in \mathbb{N}}$, then the map $n \mapsto \frac{5}{n}$ is obviously a bijection. Is that what you really meant?

Dima Braginskiy, you should use the definition of bijection in this proof. You don't appear to actually use the formal definition, just your intuition. You should should the existence of a well defined function $f$, show that it is injective, and surjective. You will need to do so in a way that is not dependent on specific examples, but is general enough to work with any input/output.

I am unsure what you mean by the codomain, so I am guessing that you mean $\left\{ \frac{5}{n} | n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \right\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.
Then your question is trivial: just define $f: \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \left\{ \frac{5}{n} | n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \right\}$ by $f (x) = \frac{5}{x}$.
($f$ is injective) Consider $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f (a) = f (b)$, or $\frac{5}{a} = \frac{5}{b}$. This implies $5 a = 5 b$, which clearly implies $a = b$, as desired.
($f$ is surjective) Consider an arbitrary element $x \in \left\{ \frac{5}{n} | n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \right\}$. Then by definition of the codomain, there exists some $n_x \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $\frac{5}{n_x} = f (n_x) = x$. Then $n_x$ is a preimage of $x$, as desired.
Since $f$ is both injective and surjective, it is bijective.

So our f(x) = 5x ?

@DimaBraginskiy No, we take $f (x) = \frac{5}{x}$.
